# what is the exact sleeping hours of swamiji?

Tags: vivekananda, swami

How many hours Swami Vivekananda use to sleep?

some say's that swami Swami Vivekananda use to sleep 10 hrs per day ,some are saying  Swami Vivekananda use to sleep 5-6 hours per day

Here im confused that   what is the exact sleeping hours of  swamiji ?

Comment: As per my understanding, all enlightened beings have a very less sleep requirement, even any normal guy who performs regular meditation and yoga has a low sleep requirement (speaking from experience), So 10 hrs sleep for swami ji is not required, 4-5 hrs should have been enough.

Answer (score 3):

Swami Vivekananda suffered from insomnia for most of his life. He stated himself to his disciple Sharatchandra Chakravarti that he fondly remembers every single day in which he was able to have a sound sleep for more than 2.5 hours.

Comment: Please do cite references.

Comment: All the references are from Bengali sources, which many people here will not understand.

Comment: @AnubrataBit The Bengali works you have read must have been translated into English. Even if that isn't the case, you can simply mention in which book you have read it. Just mention the name edition etc. That will do.

Comment: @AnubrataBit you can type the relevant Bengali line and put your own translation in English below that, and mention the name of the book as RickRoss said. Why not let people be acquainted/ comfortable with Bengali too?